# PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed

Tags: spring, netty, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

im using Web-flux/Reactive and Webclient, running it on tomcat and spring-boot.

Everything works fine. I read a lot about it. The problem seems to be that whenever you use webclient, you have to return or use the response, otherwise it will close the connection and you didn't consume it yet, and you will see a lot  of log messages saying that `the connection close prematurely`, if i had a scenario where a 404 status code is a error i could just use `OnStatus` and throw an exception, but my scenario is: when the upstream service returns a 404, i have to return manually a mono empty. so i don't use the response from web client request, i just use ClientResponse from .exchange() to check the status and handle it. My initial problem is the log messages, because is just "garbage", you don't want see a lot of it on your log messages. I've read somewhere that if it happens the connection cant be re-used as well, so it sounds really bad, but i don't know... and i just have this message when is not found, if the response is 200 it returns the object and log messages is not printed.

I tried to use 
clientResponse.BodyToMono(Void.Class)
but it doesn't work either.
the log messages keeping apearing

```
 @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(
      @Value("${http.client.connection-timeout-millis}") final int connectionTimeoutMillis,
      @Value("${http.client.socket-timeout-millis}") final int socketTimeoutMillis,
      @Value("${http.client.wire-tap-enabled}") final boolean wireTapEnabled,
      final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

    Consumer<Connection> doOnConnectedConsumer = connection ->
        connection
            .addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(socketTimeoutMillis, MILLISECONDS))
            .addHandler(new WriteTimeoutHandler(connectionTimeoutMillis, MILLISECONDS));

    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.newConnection()
        .wiretap(wireTapEnabled)
        .option(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeoutMillis)
        .doOnConnected(doOnConnectedConsumer);

    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient).compress(true)))
        .exchangeStrategies(customExchangeStrategies(objectMapper))
        .build();
  } 

// ..........

    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = getParams(t1, t2);

    return webClient.get()
        .uri(HttpUtils.buildUrl(serviceUrl, params, name))
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(this::handleClientResponse)
        .onErrorMap(Exception.class, ex -> handleUnexpectedEx(ex, name, params));
  }
```

log entries

```
2019-07-08 11:56:51.972  WARN [-,,,] 1504 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0x66c8568c, L:/127.0.0.1:62319 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] An exception has been observed post termination

reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response

2019-07-08 11:56:52.013 DEBUG [-,,,] 1504 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.left.decompressor = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-08 11:56:52.014 DEBUG [-,,,] 1504 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Non Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(WriteTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.left.decompressor = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-08 11:56:52.014 DEBUG [-,,,] 1504 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider  : [id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] onStateChange([response_incomplete], GET{uri=/service/TWFDHF?T1=1.0.0&T2=1, connection=SimpleConnection{channel=[id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]}})
2019-07-08 11:56:52.014  WARN [-,,,] 1504 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0xf50bdf8d, L:/127.0.0.1:62324 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] An exception has been observed post termination
```

log entries with wiretap enabled

```
2019-07-10 14:51:19.295 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0x677da0d4, L:/127.0.0.1:62385 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] UNREGISTERED
2019-07-10 14:51:19.541 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] CLOSE
2019-07-10 14:51:19.542 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 9 inactive connections
2019-07-10 14:51:19.542 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Channel closed, now 0 active connections and 8 inactive connections
2019-07-10 14:51:19.542 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.loggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-10 14:51:19.543 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Non Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(WriteTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.loggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-10 14:51:19.543 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] INACTIVE
2019-07-10 14:51:19.544 DEBUG [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] onStateChange(GET{uri=/dataviews/TWN_EMPLBENINFO_FIXED?version=1.0.0&sequence=1, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]}}, [response_incomplete])
2019-07-10 14:51:19.544  WARN [-,,,] 2940 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0xa7f41d1e, L:/127.0.0.1:62384 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] An exception has been observed post termination
```

and my handler

```
protected Mono handleClientResponseError(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
    clientResponse.bodyToMono(Void.class);
    Mono<ErrorResponse> errorResponse = clientResponse.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(ErrorResponse.class));

    return errorResponse.flatMap(err -> {
      log.debug("Received HttpStatusCodeException when calling {} Registry: {}", getGatewayName(),
          err.getErrorEnvelope().getMessage());

      return Mono.error(new UpStreamServiceHttpException(err, clientResponse.rawStatusCode()));
    }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> {
      log.debug("Received HttpStatusCodeException when calling {} Registry: {}", getGatewayName());

      return new UpStreamServiceHttpException("Bad Gateway", clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
    }));
  }
```

I tried already use `clientResponse.bodyToMono(Void.class);` to complete the response, but it still doesnt work, i need a way to finish the response from web-client, and then be able to re-use the connection pool and get rid of those log messages

i've created an issue on github, but it was closed, so im creating this question here. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23249

Comment: I don't understand first paragraph. Could you rewrite it more clearly?

Comment: It looks like you can enable wiretap logging. It would be interesting to see the full debug (HTTP network packets) for that response.

Comment: I edited the post, i think its more clear now, and i also added the log entries with wiretap enabled.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

so i finally found a way to finish the response and i will share here for anyone who come across this problem

before i had this:

```
 private Mono<Optional<JsonNode>> handleHttpErrorStatus(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
    if (clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
      clientResponse.bodyToMono(Void.class);
      return Mono.just(Optional.empty());
    } else {
      return handleClientResponseError(clientResponse);
    }
  }
```

But it didn't work, apparently because i wasn't returning it anyway, so after digging i tried this:

```
private Mono<Optional<JsonNode>> handleHttpErrorStatus(final ClientResponse clientResponse) {
    if (clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
      return clientResponse.bodyToMono(Void.class).thenReturn((Optional.empty()));
    } else {
      return handleClientResponseError(clientResponse);
    }
  }
```

and it works fine, i checked the wiretap logs and everything looks fine now.

```
2019-07-10 16:44:39.096 DEBUG [-,,,] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Date=Wed, 10 Jul 2019 15:44:38 GMT]
2019-07-10 16:44:39.096 DEBUG [-,,,] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] onStateChange(GET{uri=/dataviews/TWN_EMPLPIM_AVRO?version=1.0.0&sequence=1, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]}}, [response_received])
2019-07-10 16:44:39.098 DEBUG [-,bdd6433efa276f10,bdd6433efa276f10,false] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
2019-07-10 16:44:39.099 DEBUG [-,bdd6433efa276f10,bdd6433efa276f10,false] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] CLOSE
2019-07-10 16:44:39.099 DEBUG [-,bdd6433efa276f10,bdd6433efa276f10,false] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Channel cleaned, now 1 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-07-10 16:44:39.099 DEBUG [-,bdd6433efa276f10,bdd6433efa276f10,false] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Channel closed, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-07-10 16:44:39.099 DEBUG [-,bdd6433efa276f10,bdd6433efa276f10,false] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.loggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-10 16:44:39.099 DEBUG [-,bdd6433efa276f10,bdd6433efa276f10,false] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] Non Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(WriteTimeoutHandler, [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.loggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-10 16:44:39.100 DEBUG [-,,,] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] READ COMPLETE
2019-07-10 16:44:39.102 DEBUG [-,,,] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] INACTIVE
2019-07-10 16:44:39.102 DEBUG [-,,,] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0x461d8170, L:/127.0.0.1:64298 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] UNREGISTERED
2019-07-10 16:44:39.122 DEBUG [-,,,] 16260 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient              : [id: 0xbe2cb147, L:/127.0.0.1:64295 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8990] READ: 398B
```

Comment: Hi 
Could you please check this? I am having a similar issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129231/webclient-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-direct-buffer-memory/65133879#65133879

Comment: That is because `bodyToMono` returns a `Mono` itself. 
You want to consume the payload first before doing something with it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that I kept battling with for 5 days wondering what exactly I had done wrong after a new feature deployment. I finally had my Eureka moment.

So in my *Dockerfile* I had exposed the default port *8080*.

[image]
Which meant the tomcat server in my application image would always be available on that port. My container also had to be running on port 8080 (inside my .yml file)
[image]

before I apply the port mapping directive to map the external port 9003 on my linux host to the 8080 in the container.
[image]

What I missed was that, during the deployment of the services using the **docker-compose file**, I forgot to change the **server.port** in the application.yml file to 8080 so that the port mapping could happen. I left it as 9003 *(because I was using 9003 on my local machine to test the app)* which meant anytime I started the containers using docker-compose, my service port was mapped as

> ***0.0.0.0:9003 -> 9003/tcp*** instead of ***0.0.0.0:9003 -> 8080/tcp***.

This was why the api-gateway kept throwing the

> PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed

because there was actually no internal port 9003 found in the container instance of my microservice for the 9003 on the linux host to map to.

I just had to change the **9003** in my application.yml to **8080** and that was all.