# Webclient : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, cloud-foundry

I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory error at the web client.

The batch job runs daily. It fails twice then passed in the third attempt.

```
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.rethrow(RetryTemplate.java:532) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientDoOnError$OnErrorTcpClient.connect(HttpClientDoOnError.java:242) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar:0.9.11.RELEASE]
```

JVM memory configuration which I found in the log. It is running in the cloud foundry.

```
JVM Memory Configuration: -Xmx342549K -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=194026K
```

Code where it fails:

```
    @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${remote.retry.maxAttempts}}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${remote.retry.delay}}"))
    public Optional<JobStatusResponseDTO> getStatus(String jobNumber, String accountNumber) {
        return broadridgeClient.getStatus(accountNumber, jobNumber);
    }

      @CircuitBreaker(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${remote.circuitBreaker.maxAttempts}}",
            openTimeoutExpression = "#{${remote.circuitBreaker.openTimeout}}", resetTimeoutExpression = "#{${remote.circuitBreaker.resetTimeout}}")
    public Optional<JobStatusResponseDTO> getStatus(String account, String jobNumber) {

        JobStatusRequestDTO request = new JobStatusRequestDTO();
        request.setAccount(account);
        request.setJobNumber(jobNumber);

        JobStatusResponseDTO jobStatus;
        jobStatus = client.post()
                .uri(PATH)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                .exchange()
                .elapsed()
                .flatMap(response -> {
                    
                    if (response.getT2().statusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    } else if (isClientOrServerError(response.getT2())) {
                        return Mono.error(new RemoteClientException(String.format("Job status is not received: %s", response.getT2().statusCode())));
                    }
                    return response.getT2().bodyToMono(JobStatusResponseDTO.class);
                })
                .block();
        return Optional.ofNullable(jobStatus);
    }
```

Edit 1:

I also found that cloud foundary is setting a low mwmory for heap
I am using CF task to run it.

```
cf run-task ipbol-proxy-batch "JAVA_OPTS=\"-agentpath:\$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE=printHeapHistogram=1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=\$TMPDIR -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=\$(nproc) -Dspring.batch.job.names=${job_name} -Dbatch.run.historic=${run_historic_files} -Dorg.cloudfoundry.security.keymanager.enabled=false -Dorg.cloudfoundry.security.trustmanager.enabled=true -Djava.ext.dirs= -Djava.security.properties=\$PWD/.java-buildpack/java_security/java.security \$JAVA_OPTS\" && CALCULATED_MEMORY=\$(\$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-3.13.0_RELEASE -totMemory=\$MEMORY_LIMIT -loadedClasses=31842 -poolType=metaspace -stackThreads=250 -vmOptions=\"\$JAVA_OPTS\") && echo JVM Memory Configuration: \$CALCULATED_MEMORY && JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS \$CALCULATED_MEMORY\" && KEYSTORE_PARAMS=\$(\$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java -jar \$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/keystore-manager-0.1.1.jar) && JAVA_OPTS=\"\$JAVA_OPTS \$KEYSTORE_PARAMS\" && MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2 VCAP_SERVICES=\$(for i in {1..10}; do \${PWD}/.java-buildpack/mv_decryptor/jpmc-mvdecryptor && exit 0; sleep 3; done; kill \$\$) SERVER_PORT=\$PORT eval exec \$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java \$JAVA_OPTS -cp \$PWD/.::\$PWD/.java-buildpack/container_security_provider/container_security_provider-1.16.0_RELEASE.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher" ipbol-proxy-batch
```

**Edit 2:**

I have updated the code to consume the response in every case. Still, I am getting the same "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory"

```
public Optional<JobStatusResponseDTO> getStatus(String account, String jobNumber) {

        JobStatusRequestDTO request = new JobStatusRequestDTO();
        request.setAccount(account);
        request.setJobNumber(jobNumber);
        Optional<JobStatusResponseDTO> responseDTO = Optional.empty();

        final Object block = client.post()
                .uri(PATH)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                .exchange()
                .elapsed()
                .flatMap(response -> {
                   
                    if (response.getT2().statusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
                        return response.getT2().bodyToMono(Void.class).thenEmpty(Mono.empty());

                    } else if (isClientOrServerError(response.getT2())) {
                        return response.getT2().bodyToMono(Void.class).thenEmpty(Mono.error(new RemoteClientException(String.format("Job status is not received: %s", response.getT2().statusCode()))));
                    }
                    return response.getT2().bodyToMono(JobStatusResponseDTO.class);
                })
                .block();
        
        if(block!= null && block instanceof JobStatusResponseDTO)
        {
            responseDTO = Optional.of((JobStatusResponseDTO)block);
        }
        return responseDTO;
    }
```

I don't have spring webflux 5.3 in organization repo. So can't use that.

This is the **default memory configuration**

```
-Xmx1387828K -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=197323K
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Spring 5.3 the `exchange()` method has been deprecated on the web client due to the fact it opens up the possibility of memory and connection leaks. By using `exchange()` you take on the responsibility to consume the response content for every single scenario.

From the code example above, you are not consuming the body in success and error cases.

You can also set the following property to get some additional information from netty on where the leaks are coming from.

> -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=paranoid

[Exchange Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange--)

[Netty Leak Detection Docs](https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#leak-detection-levels)

Comment: Hi, Could you please check the edit 2. I am still getting the same error.